# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' from Python 2.X to 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to work on a project and I have a code but it's written in python 2.X
I'm currently working on Python 3.X and when i try to

`X= abs(int(f'fractionfactor:e'.split('e')[-1]))`

in Python 2.X the result of .split will send back just the decimal part for exemple int(str(5/2)) will give me in return "2"
but in python 3.X i'll get "2.5" for the same code
here is the full part i'm currently stuck in

```
def format_value(valuetoformatx, fractionfactorx):
    value= valuetoformatx
    fractionfactor= fractionfactorx
    Precision= abs(int(f'fractionfactor:e'.split('e')[-1]))
    FormattedValue= float(':0.0{}f'.format(value,Precision))
    return FormattedValue

def parPriceinfo(ticker,client):
    info= client.get_symbol_info(ticker)
    minPrice= pd.to_numeric(info['filters'][0]["minPrice"])
    return minPrice

def pairQtyinfo(ticker,client):
    info= client.get_symbol_info(ticker)
    minQty= pd.to_numeric(info['filters'][2]['minQty'])
    return minQty
```

error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I hope that i've provided enough information. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an f-string, you need to put `{}` around the variable to format and the format expression.

```
Precision= abs(int(f'fractionfactor:e'.split('e')[-1]))
```

should be

```
Precision= abs(int(f'{fractionfactor:e}'.split('e')[-1]))
```

Comment: yeah i've just changed it and it works
thanks man and just for the record 
i have to also change 

`FormattedValue= float(':0.0{}f'.format(value,Precision))` 

to 

`FormattedValue= float('{:0.0{}f}'.format(value,Precision))`

@barmar thanks again !